# Cauchy preserving implies continuity of function

Tags: continuity, cauchy-sequences

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow (0,1)$. Prove or disprove :

if $\{f(a_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence whenever $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is then $f$ is continuous.

Suggested solution from the book is the following:

If $f$ is not continuous there is in $(0,1)$ an $x_0$ and a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ and $f(x_n)\not\rightarrow f(x_0)$. If $y_{2n}=x_n$, $y_{2n-1}=x_0$ for $n=1,2,3...$ then $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence and $\{f(y_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not!

I am really confused why $(y_n)$ is Cauchy and $\{f(y_n)\}$ is not. We do not even know how $f$ looks like, so how can we justify that $\{f(y_n)\}$? Thank you for all explanation in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Because since $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$ exists $s>0$ such that forall $m \in \Bbb{N}$ exists $n \geq m$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)| \geq s$

Using this and the sequence $y_n$  you defined ,you can reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x_0$ and every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

On the other hand, $\bigl(f(y_n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not convergent, and therefore it is not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: well, the point is I cannot see why $y_n$ converges to $x_0$? Could you please provide more some details?

Comment: Since the $y_n$'s with even $n$ converge to $x_0$ and the $y_n$'s with odd $n$ also converge to $x_0$, the limit of the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is $x_0$.

Comment: The tails of the sequence $(y_n)=(x_0,x_2,x_0,x_4,...) $ do not seem to tend to $x_0$ because it oscillates between $x_0$ and some $x_{2n}$.

Comment: The sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the sequence$$x_0,x_1,x_0,x_2,x_0,x_3,\ldots,$$Half of them are equal to $x_0$; the other half converges to $x_0$. So, where's the doubt? Do you want a $\varepsilon-N$ proof?

Comment: I am not sure when you said the other half converges to $x_0$, do you mean $(x_1,x_3,x_5,..)\rightarrow x_0$?. If so, I still cannot get it why? To be honest, if the $\varepsilon-N$ proof help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Take $\varepsilon>0$. There is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies\lvert x_n-x_0\rvert<\varepsilon$. Then, if $n\geqslant2N$, $n$ is either odd or even. If $n$ is even, then $y_n=x_{n/2}$ and, since $\frac n2\geqslant N$, $\lvert y_n-x_0\rvert=\lvert x_{n/2}-x_0\rvert<\varepsilon$. If $n$ is odd, then $y_n=x_0$, and therefore $\lvert y_n-x_0\rvert=0<\varepsilon$. So, I proved that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=x_0$ by the definition.